# How to fit a*e**bx function via gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, exponential

**Upon running this code on my file, it fits nothing.**

```
f1(x) = a*e**(b*x)
a = -1
b = 10000
fit f1(x) 'myFile.txt' via a,b
plot 'myFile.txt' with points lc rgb"blue" title ' '
```

Does gnuplot understand 'e' or do we need to declare its value? *i.e. 2.7182.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `exp` function for this:

```
f1(x) = a*exp(b*x)
a = -1
b = 10000
fit f1(x) 'myFile.txt' via a,b
plot 'myFile.txt' with points lc rgb"blue" title ' '
```